# Expo React Native APK Video Recording Issue: Starting Capture on useEffect

Tags: android, react-native, expo, apk

I'm using Expo React Native along with the Expo Camera component to record videos.
My goal is to initiate video recording as soon as the camera component is opened.

When running my app through Expo, everything works perfectly, and the recorded videos turn out as expected. However, when I build an APK (Android Package) with the same code and try to record a video, the resulting files have a duration of 0 seconds, displaying only a still image from the moment I press the record button to stop recording. What's peculiar is that the videos become longer if I hold the stop button for a longer duration.

```
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { CameraType, Camera } from 'expo-camera';
// import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

function TestRecord() {
    const [permission, requestPermission] = Camera.useCameraPermissions();
    const cameraRef = useRef<Camera>(null);
    const isRecordingRef = useRef<boolean>(false);
    const [cameraReady, setCameraReady] = useState<boolean>(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (cameraRef.current && !isRecordingRef.current && cameraReady && permission && permission.granted) {
            isRecordingRef.current = true;

            startRecordingInterval();
        }
    }, [cameraReady, permission]);

    const startRecordingInterval = async () => {
        if (cameraRef.current) {
            try {
                const videoData = await cameraRef.current.recordAsync();

                //receive Video
            } catch (error) {
                console.log("error: ", error);
            }
        }
    }

    const stopRecording = () => {
        if (cameraRef.current && isRecordingRef.current) {
            isRecordingRef.current = false;
            cameraRef.current.stopRecording();
        }
    };

    if (!permission || permission?.granted === false) {
        return <View />;
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Camera
                ref={cameraRef}
                type={CameraType.back}
                style={styles.cameraContainer}
                onCameraReady={() => {
                    setCameraReady(true);
                }}
                onMountError={(error) => {
                    // do something
                }}
            >
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={stopRecording}>
                        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Stop Recording</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </Camera>
        </View >
    )
}

export default TestRecord;
```

I would like to understand why video recording does not work as expected in the APK version and how to correct it

I attempted to add a button component to trigger the recording:

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={startRecordingInterval}>
  <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Start Recording</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Although it works with this approach on the builded APK, it doesn't meet my requirements.

Is there a way to start the recording as soon as the camera is opened without relying on a button click event?